# Application level variables in android getting nulled

Tags: android

I have developed an Android Application. To keep the user logged in, I am storing their username and password in a class that extends `Application`. If the user exits the application without logging out, a backgound service will start which will use the user credentials (username and password) stored in the Application context. 
This worked very well for me. But now I have installed facebook in my phone (Samsung galaxy Ace). It has a service that occupies 37 MB of the RAM. Now when I run the background service of my application. The application level variable get killed when I play a game or sometimes even when I lock the screen (the username and password become null).
What is happening? What other way is there to keep the user logged in? I don't want to use sqlite database to store the username/password. You can easily see the values of the table.


**Note**
I still have 38 MB of RAM available even with this facebook running. my app uses only 544kb of memory.

**EDIT1**
This might seem surprising but I have not made any changes in my code. But now the Apllication variables (username and password) lives on even when I open threee or four applications. In the question above I said that the `Application` vairables become null as soon as I even lock the screen. But now they seem to be persisting even when I play play a game (with another application open!). So clearly it not the memory constraint that kills the `Application` variables. 
What is the reason for this? What determines the killing of the application level variables?

Answer (score 1):

You can use SharedPreferences to accomplish what you are looking for.

```
SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
Editor editor = preferences.getEditor();
editor.putBoolean("user_logged_in", true);
// ... anything else you want
editor.commit();
```

Also you can do the same to retrieve your preferences as well.

```
SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
boolean userLoggedIn = preferences.getBoolean("user_logged_in", false);
```

How ever keeping your data secure is another part of the story. These methods work well with devices that are not rooted. And security depends upon encrypting your credentials (preferably using asymmetric cryptographic algorithms.)

Comment: Try overriding the onDestroy() method and try experimenting with your App's life cycle. You may stumble upon a few clues.

Comment: OnDestroy() method of what? Like I said. all the actvities are closed before the background service is started. Just the variables of the class extending "Application" are present. How can I detect the nullifying of these variables or even prevent it?

Comment: Sorry, try overriding the onLowMemory() and onTerminate() methods of your Application class.

Answer (score 0):

You can only use encryption for username/ password. Searching around will give you some sample codes. In case the user powers off his device, your app stops too.

Answer (score 0):

In your background service oncreate,call setForeground method:

```
public void onCreate() {
super.onCreate();
...
this.setForeground(true);
...
}
```

setForeground method can guard your service against killed by system.
I think this can help you. ^-^

Comment: my background service is an intent service. i does not contain any on Create method. Moreover it runs in a separate thread.